# Google Maps API xCode

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, viewcontroller

I've been trying to **find some info on using Google maps** for a project I'm doing now. But I've been kinda confused.  I want to use the

> main view-controller in the storyboard to have a search bar

and you *can type in your town or zip code, and it will take you to another view-controller with Google maps on it and it will show all the McDonald or whatever specific restaurant or store around you or in your city.* This is my first time using Google maps API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Android studio for create map and for the API key "Google console" and turn on the API then go to login section and get your API key

Then you have to get all position of McDonalds and add Markers to the map